# Subview for multiple xib files

Tags: xcode

I have a project that calls for a custom menu screen to be placed on each xib file. I understand that I can do this from creating a view and adding it as a subview.

I want to create that view in 1 file and then call it wherever I need it, just not sure how to achieve this.

Any help please?...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of me doing exactly this.

[Creating Loadable Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954485/using-interface-builder-to-create-loabable-views)

I did this to create custom tableview cell's but this can be done with any type of class.

the key is that the items have a Custom Class set in the Interface builder.

====== Update ======

Another Thing I had not thought of is. You may be wanting to create a view of a specific type and just put that view into each of your XIB files.

If that is the case. then you can create a New class that is a SubClass of UIView

Then you just add a UIView to your xib (without anything in it) and set its "Custom Class" value in the identity explorer. This will tell Objective C that this UIView is Actually the "Custom Class" type. and it will Alloc init your custom class and put that there. In this event you can build your menu or whatever else using code and it would be put into the class where the blank UIView you inserted earlier was actually at.

**My Most common case**

Is to use a "Container" UIView that is connected to an outlet and then use the nibLoader method as linked to above to pull the view out of the nib it was created in, and then add that object as a subview of the container

```
@interface HomeViewController  ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyCustomView *customView;

@end

@implementation HomeViewController 

@synthesize customViewContainer = _customViewContainer; // IBOutlet from header
@synthesize customView = _customView;
- (MyCustomView*) customView{
    if (_customView == nil){ // Lazy Load
        // Load From Nib Loader linked to above
    }
    return _customView;
}

- (void) viewDidAppearAnimated:(BOOL) animated {
    this.customView.frame = this.customViewContainer.bounds;
    [this.customViewContainer addSubView:this.customView];
}

@end
```